# Validating with ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

This is what I've done so far.

```
<span id="error_para">*</span> Username:<input type="text" name="field_username" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter Unique Username.');" oninput="setCustomValidity('');" required id="username"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <input type='button' id='check_username_availability' name="button1" value='Check Availability'><br />  
 <br />
 <div id='username_availability_result'></div>  <br />

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //the min chars for username  
    var min_chars = 3;  

    //result texts   
    var checking_html = 'Checking...';  

    //when button is clicked  
    $('#check_username_availability').click(function(){  
        //run the character number check  
        if($('#username').val().length < min_chars){  
            //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '  
            $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error);  
        }else{  
            //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check  
            $('#username_availability_result').html(checking_html);  
            check_availability();  
        }  
    });  

 });  
//function to check username availability  
function check_availability(){  

    //get the username  
    var username = $('#username').val();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("validateusername.php", { username: username }, 
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result == 1 ){  
                //show that the username is available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');  
            }else if(result == 0){  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');  
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not procced');  
            }  

    });
```

But it just shows that username is not proceed.I think that there is a problem with data transfer with my php file.

my validateusername.php file:

```
<?php


if( isset( $_POST['button1'] ) )
{
//get the username  
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "jigar", "admin", "demo1");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT username FROM logindata WHERE     username= '$username' " ) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "0";  
} else {   
    echo "1";   
}

$mysqli->close();
}   
?>
```

Comment: U r not getting any response from Php

Comment: And u r mixing mysqli procedural and OOP style together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax you are only sending username in ajax data:

```
$.post("validateusername.php", { username: username },
```

And in PHP you are using

```
if( isset( $_POST['button1'] ) )
```

Your ajax request not contains this. It should be

```
if( isset( $_POST['username'] ) )
```

Or

```
if( count( $_POST) > 0)
```

**Side note**:

Don't know why are you mixing mysqli procedural and OOP style together.

Comment: @jigar-solanki test it.

Comment: i have tested your code it worked fine but its still shows me that username not proceed. i have printed the result variable it works fine prints 0 and 1.any idea what is problem.

Comment: @jigar-solanki need to debug use console.log(result); inside the ajax success or alert(result); chk what r u getting

Comment: tried it gives html file which contains 1 in body tag.

Comment: and 0 for occupied username.

Comment: @jigar-solanki well try to use .... echo 1;exit; and echo 0;exit;      and let me know else we will use json if not solve with exit.

Comment: i think thats why if condition is not working because it cannot reading value  from html file and shows else block.

Comment: yes u r right after using exit; it breaks html file from 1.but upper part of the file is still there.

Comment: @jigar-solanki this link will help u to understand how to send text or json from Php stackoverflow.com/questions/8265699/ajax-php-jquery-echo-ing-back-data

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tested bit of code but you could try instead of:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "0";  
} else {  
    echo "1";      
}
```

This:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) {
    if($row['username'] == $username) {
        echo 1;
        $found = 1;
    }
}

if(!isset($found)) { echo 0; }
```

Comment: But I didn't see any difference brother

Comment: Also, I noticed that with JQuery you need to specify the path including `/` in this statement: `$.post("validateusername.php", { username: username }, `

Comment: No OP checking with button1 which is not defined or no need chk my answer

Comment: now i understand but i think i have to print 0 and 1 vice-versa in your code.and does i have to add root to file url if its in same folder.?

Comment: yea, see @devpro answer for a solution to your issue also. Your ajax is sending the paramater username so you must fetch it in $_POST as ['username']

Comment: @KyleE4K Mixing procedural and OOP styles of mysqli should work.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation